# Riley Riddle #2: Wasting my time

Tags: riddle

The first was your friend had you need work the States
End with Toronto's host of African art Greats
Sandwiched is a form of one-way communiqué
Together is a symbol, done your own way

Comment: Please don't announce a winner in the question proper, just accept El-Guest's answer -- that's how it works here: The accepted answer will be shown immediately under the question and gets a fat green tick mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only got enough for a partial answer here, but I am loving the Canadian references!

The first was your friend had you need work the States

> You need help from the INS, the [Immigration and Naturalization Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immigration_and_Naturalization_Service).

End with Toronto's host of African art Greats

> This is the [NIA Centre for the Arts](https://www.niacentre.org/)

Sandwiched is a form of one-way communiqué

> This is a SIGN

Together is a symbol, done your own way

> INSIGNIA!!!!!!!

Comment: Another option for one of the clues: Rot13(uggcf://auneb.pbz/)

Comment: That's a little further west than the area of Toronto I'm used to, great find @cobaltduck!!

Comment: Are IM's one-way? Even most posts or notes can be responded to...

Comment: I couldn't get anything to fit with the Toronto clue as a suffix...there aren't that many words that end in either acronym...could the one way communication be rot13(enqvb), ie. either r13(NZ) or r13(SZ)? @flashstorm

Comment: I can tell you that the one-way communique is a reference to everyday life. I would take very very strong odds that you would have encountered one today, and I don't know anything about you.

Comment: I like you edit! It's still not right though :). I'm happy to share more clues if you feel you need them

Comment: I'll start by saying you are wrong on all three clues so far, but I like your thinking.

Comment: I'd definitely appreciate more clues! Is any one of the three correct now? I feel a bit more confident for the communique...?  _Edit: Darn it!_

Comment: Here's a clue: when I make a reference, it's because that reference is necessary (unless it's to fit the rhyming scheme). The problem with AGO or ROM is that, well, is African a necessary aspect of those answers?

Comment: @flashstorm, cobaltduck found an African-specific art gallery (Nharo); although I found one a little further east called Zim. AGO has one of the biggest African art collections in North America, that being said; I'm not too sure I know of that many specific galleries.

Comment: He's on the right track, but there's more to art then just galleries :)

Comment: If you go to [rot13.com](https://rot13.com/), you can copy and paste the text to translate the answer. The website performs a shift of 13 letters in order to hide any spoilers in the comments. The website referenced is [here](https://nharo.com/).

Comment: He's on the right track, but there's so much more to art than just galleries ;)

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhh man this was a relief @flashstorm

Comment: The final word is right! But, the first clue is technically wrong. Want to take a stab? Clue: Why did I reference the States specifically?

Comment: Hmmm...I've got one other thought, but would appreciate a hint if it's incorrect!

Comment: Insurance isn't US-specific :P. I feel as though you may be abbreviating your efforts.

Comment: The abbreviation you're looking for is now the USCIS, but very nice riddle @flashstorm!!

Comment: Oops! I literally didn't look anything up when coming up with this, so that's totally on me!

Comment: That's impressive! How did you hear about the Toronto centre? I'm pretty sure I've walked past it a bunch of times in the last little while and didn't remember it for this riddle :P

Comment: I went on a date to a poetry showcase there a year ago, so it came to mind easily.

Comment: Solid!! Nice to meet a fellow GTA resident/Ontarian on here :D

Comment: Drat.  I was certain I was on to something, even though all words ending in *-naro* tend to be Spanish, not English.  I am still left wondering if the title was supposed to be a clue or not.

Comment: Well I mean...thinking whether the title was a hint or not certainly....wasted your time...? (Bad joke, I'm sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the credit here goes to El-Guest here, I'm simply attempting at the first part

The first is your friend should you need work the States

> You need Immigration and Naturalization Services, or the INS

End with Toronto's host of African art Greats

> This is the [NIA Centre for the Arts](https://www.niacentre.org/)

Sandwiched is a form of one-way communiqué

> This is a SIGN

Together is a symbol, done your own way

> INSIGNIA!!!!!!!